# How to include magnetic loss in transmission line equations for coaxial cable?

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microwave

I'm trying to calculate the attenuation per unit length (\$\alpha\$) of a coaxial cable, including dielectric dissipation (\$\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}\$), magnetic dissipation (\$\mu^{\prime\prime}\$) and the surface resistance of the conductors (\$R_\mathrm{s}\$).

Following the derivation of the conductance-per-unit-length (\$G\$) in Pozar, I start with the power dissipated in the dielectric per unit volume (Eqn. 1.92):

$$P_\ell = \dfrac{\sigma}{2}\int\limits_V\left\vert\bar{E}\right\vert^2\,dv + \dfrac{\omega}{2}\int\limits_V\left(\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}\left\vert\bar{E}\right\vert^2 + \mu^{\prime\prime}\left\vert\bar{H}\right\vert^2\right)\,dv$$

Per unit length (and assuming \$\sigma=0\$), this becomes:

$$P_\mathrm{d} = \dfrac{\omega\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}}{2}\int\limits_S\left\vert\bar{E}\right\vert^2\,ds + \dfrac{\omega\mu^{\prime\prime}}{2}\int\limits_S\left\vert\bar{H}\right\vert^2\,ds$$

where the electric and magnetic fields inside a coaxial cable are given by (see Ex. 2.1):

$$\bar{E}=\dfrac{V_0\hat{\rho}}{\rho\ln b/a}\\
\bar{H}=\dfrac{I_0\hat{\phi}}{2\pi\rho}$$

The integrals are:

$$\int\limits_S\vert\bar{E}\vert^2\,ds = \dfrac{\vert V_0\vert^2}{\left(\ln b/a\right)^2}\int\limits_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{\rho=a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{\rho^2}\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi = \dfrac{2\pi\,\vert V_0\vert^2}{\ln b/a} \\ 
\int\limits_S\vert\bar{H}\vert^2\,ds = \dfrac{\vert I_0\vert^2}{\left(2\pi\right)^2}\int\limits_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{\rho=a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{\rho^2}\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi = \dfrac{\ln b/a\,\vert I_0\vert^2}{2\pi} $$

The power dissipation per unit length is then:

$$P_\mathrm{d} = \dfrac{\omega\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}}{2}\dfrac{2\pi\,\vert V_0\vert^2}{\ln b/a} + \dfrac{\omega\mu^{\prime\prime}}{2}\dfrac{\ln b/a\,\vert I_0\vert^2}{2\pi}$$

Again, following Pozar, I convert the power dissipation into a conductance term. From circuit theory, \$P_\mathrm{d} = G\vert V_0\vert^2/2 = \vert I_o\vert^2/2G\$. We can represent this dissipation as two conductances in parallel:

$$P_\mathrm{d,e} = \dfrac{G_\mathrm{e}\vert V_0\vert^2}{2} = \dfrac{\omega\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}}{2}\dfrac{2\pi\,\vert V_0\vert^2}{\ln b/a}\\
P_\mathrm{d,m} = \dfrac{\vert I_o\vert^2}{2G_\mathrm{m}} = \dfrac{\omega\mu^{\prime\prime}}{2}\dfrac{\ln b/a\,\vert I_0\vert^2}{2\pi}$$

Solving for \$G_\mathrm{e}\$ and \$G_\mathrm{m}\$ gives:

$$G_\mathrm{e} = \omega\,\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}\,\dfrac{2\pi}{\ln b/a}~~~\mathrm{[S/m]} \\ 
G_\mathrm{m} = \dfrac{1}{\omega\,\mu^{\prime\prime}}\,\dfrac{2\pi}{\ln b/a}~~~\mathrm{[S/m]} $$

This final result doesn't seem right... because \$G_\mathrm{m}\$ decreases with frequency (it should go up!). Should magnetic dissipation be included instead as a resistance-per-unit-length (\$R\$)?

Comment: In the process of writing out my question, I found the answer... magnetic dissipation needs to be included in the resistance-per-unit-length term (\$R\$). The additional resistance per unit length is:$$R=\omega\mu^{\prime\prime}\dfrac{\ln b/a}{2\pi}$$. This matches my HFSS simulations that I used a sanity check.

Comment: It’s OK to go ahead and make that an answer, and not just a comment.

Comment: ...even recommended to do as @relayman357 says, since the search function does not include the comments, which means that future "clients", searching for similar problems, will find this question listed as having no answer, so they'll skip it, even if it has a solution. By all means, please do answer it.

Comment: Thanks, I've copied my comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of writing out my question, I found the answer... magnetic dissipation needs to be included in the resistance-per-unit-length term (\$R\$). The additional resistance-per-unit-length is:

$$R=\omega\mu^{\prime\prime}\,\dfrac{\ln b/a}{2\pi}$$

This matches the HFSS simulation that I used as a sanity check.

This is added in series with the resistance-per-unit-length caused by the surface resistance of the conductors.